# Basic Linux Bash Scripting while / for

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Doing my first steps in bash scripting. Managed to do 5/7 exercices so far, stuck in the last two and I cant find a way to solve it.

Here’s a better translation of the requested exercice, the same should be solved using simple commands like sed, echo, cat, uniq, tr, grep, wc, etc:

Write the command line which displays the number of users whose default shell is one of the shells available on your machine. When the command is executed, for each of the shells we would have a result of the same form as the following:

> - 0 users have for shell / bin / sh
> - 11 users have for shell / bin / bash
> - 0 users have for shell / usr / bin / sh
> - 0 users have for shell / usr / bin / bash

@Todd

I did it this morning, your grep redirecting input gave me the idea. This is how I did it:

- `result=$(grep -of <(echo $SHELL) /etc/passwd | uniq -c)`
- `count=$(echo $result I awk -F” “ '{print $1}')`
- `shell=$(echo $result | awk -F” “'{print $2}')`
- `echo $result | while read i; do`
- `echo $count utilisateurs ont pour shell $shell`
- `done`

Comment: Not sure how can there be 0 users of a certain login shell if it is not in the `passwd` file.

Comment: @Jetchisel available login shells are stored in `/etc/shells`

Comment: @Aserre, yes that could be the case but the OP has not mentioned  that file or posted in the code.

Comment: @Jetchisel As they said they have just started bash scripting, I suspect they didn't know about this file

Comment: And yet `/etc/passwd` showed up in the code, It is better to ask the OP to clarify things a bit.

Comment: The code is what I managed to pull so far which seems messy an wrong. Yes, I could get the result I’m being asked copying and pasting the same line 4 times and changing the grep query but it seems horrible. The teacher wants us to search how many users belong to each one of those shells he listed, list the quantity and the name.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please show your code and explain what's wrong with it (inputs, expected outputs, actual outputs). And also take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), maybe, to better understand [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). [This discussion about homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is interesting too for students.

Answer (score 1):

### Unix Utilities and Bash Process Substitution

In Bash, there are a lot of ways to do this. However, you don't really need Bash itself to solve this from a practical standpoint. Standard *nix tools will do just fine, provided you link them up correctly. For example, if the specific format of your output isn't the main point:

```sh
$ grep -of <(grep '^/.*$' /etc/shells) /etc/passwd | sort | uniq -c
   11 /bin/bash
    8 /bin/sh
    4 /usr/local/bin/fish
```

This basically greps your shells from /etc/shells, and then grep treats *that* output as a file to read expressions from to match against /etc/passwd. It then pipes the results to the sort and uniq utilities to count the occurrences. It relies on process substitution, which not all shells have or express the same way, but your question was tagged with Bash so avoiding Bashisms isn't a major concern.

However, since not all shells have the process substitution redirections that Bash does, solutions like this aren't 100% portable across different shells. There's usually a similar way to do it, but sometimes portability across systems and shells can really matter. In any case, this shows how powerful grep, pipes, and process substitution can be.

Once you have the raw data, you can format the output with printf, awk, or even sed if you want it in a different format. However, if the point is to count shell usage, that's an easy way to do it in Bash or zsh.

### A More Portable Alternative

A more complex (but also more-portable) alternative is to use xargs as the core element of your pipeline. For example:

```sh
$ grep -o '^/.*$' /etc/shells |
    xargs -I{} -L1 -- sh -c 'echo "{}"; grep -Fc "{}" /etc/passwd' |
    xargs -n2
/bin/bash 11
/bin/csh 0
/bin/ksh 0
/bin/sh 8
/bin/tcsh 0
/bin/zsh 0
/usr/local/bin/fish 4
```

This will find all the shells in /etc/shells, pass them to a Bourne script one at a time to print the shell's path and have grep's fixed-string matcher count the occurrences in /etc/passwd, and then pipe the output to xargs again to join the lines back up two at a time.

The main benefit of this approach is it will list *all* shells, whether or not anyone is using them. You can even change the last line to `tac | xargs -n2` if you want the numbers to be listed before the name of the shell.

Comment: I did it this morning, your grep redirecting input gave me the idea. Edited the first post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

This how I understood your question, One approach using arrays, Associative array included.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A Shell_and_Users

while IFS=: read -ra lines; do
  login_shell="${lines[-1]}"
  ((Shell_and_Users["$login_shell"]++))
done < /etc/passwd
```

---

To check the value of the associative array `Shell_and_Users` run:

```
declare -p Shell_and_Users
```

---

Now loop through the associative array to print the desired output.

```
for i in "${!Shell_and_Users[@]}"; do
  printf -- '- %d users have shell %s\n' "${Shell_and_Users[$i]}" "$i"
done
```

---

If that is not the case then edit the question and add more details if the file `/etc/shells` should be parse/involve, since the solution above will never print `0 users`.

Comment: I dont have any idea of what I just did but I copied to try to understand a bit. I think that the output he gave is because in some part of the script one should run “cat /etc/passwd | grep “/bin/sh” | wc -l which would be 0.

Comment: Ok , just go with the `cat` if that is what the examiner/professor gave you but it is a classic example of [UUoC](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#cat), Also `grep -c '/bin/sh$' /etc/passwd` should suffice

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `awk` can be used, you can try this

```
$ cat awk.script
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=":"
} $NF=="/bin/bash" {
    count_bash++
    bash=$NF
} $NF=="/usr/bin/bash" {
    count_bash2++
    bash2=$NF
} $NF=="/bin/sh" {
    count_sh++
    sh=$NF
} $NF=="/usr/bin/sh" {
    count_sh2++
    sh2=$NF
} END {
    print count_bash " users have a shell for "bash "\n" \
          count_bash2" users have a shell for "bash2 "\n" \
          count_sh " users have a shell for "sh "\n" \
          count_sh2" users have a shell for "sh2 "\n" \
}
```

This will give output similar to your expected output, however, if the shell is not in use, you will get an empty output with no value or path which may not be ideal.

**Output**

```
$ awk -f awk.script /etc/passwd
24 users have a shell for /bin/bash
 users have a shell for
2 users have a shell for /bin/sh
 users have a shell for
```

Comment: If you use `awk` you can simplify all this with an associative array: `{c[$NF]++} END {for (s in c) print c[s] " bla " s}`. And note that password files sometimes contain comments (`#...`) that should be skipped. I think non commented lines never contain `#` (not 100% sure), so adding a condition like `!/#/` to `{c[$NF]++}` should be enough.